# Aligning google aps script gadget on google page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I've create a google apps script chart which looks fine when I run `publish > deploy > Test web app for your latest code`.

However, once it's inserted as script gadget on a page of a google site, I can't modify its horizontal alignment:

1. clicking the left/center/right icon to modify alignment of the script gadget while editing the page in google site does nothing
2. I've tried deploying the app as `UiApp.createApplication()` as-is and then within a horizontal panel with various settings of `HorizontalAlignment`: nothing changes.

Creating charts with google apps script is easy enough, but aligning the results on a google page is frustrating.

```
  uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('TheTitle').add( chart );

  var hpanel = uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
  hpanel.add(chart).setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)

  uiApp.add(hpanel);
  return uiApp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the width of the hpanel to like `var hpanel = uiApp.createHorizontalPanel().setWidth(800)` and you may notice the alignment change then.

Comment: It sure does, thanks. Seems this means that no specific size setting is _not_ equivalent to a 100% default..